# Calculate the fourier transformation in python

Tags: python, algorithm, continuous-fourier

I have a (theoretical) algorithm I want to implement in python. In this algorithm I have a start function called `f`, and I have to apply the fourier transformation and the inverse fourier transformation several times on this function. Is there a way to do that in python? I only found the DFT, where my function has to be several discrete points (and not a continuous function). Is it possible to create a fourier transformation function in python which can handle a continuous function? Or should I rather generate a huge amount of points representing the function, and then calculate the FT and IFT of them?

The function is:

```
A(z,t) = C* exp(i*z*N^2/2L)/(cosh(t/T))
```

Comment: Please add a link to the FT and add your function.

Comment: @User: What do you mean with "add a link to the FT"? Should I link to Wikipedia?

Comment: Yes. Two people  do not understand your question. It could be because of that. Also this is a programming forum, no math forum. So you would need to write a Python function if that is possible. I do not know of any Fourier Transform that is not discrete so I will not be of help.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to link to the Fourier transform Wikipedia page, @User. If people don't know what it is then they can't answer this question.

Comment: @arc_lupus You should change how you are describing your function. Mathjax isn't supported on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you know [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)?

Comment: @Phillip: Sounds really interesting, I'll take a look!

Comment: @Phillip: Unfortunately sympy is not able to calculate the FT in a sufficient way...

Comment: What is unsufficient about how sympy calculates the fourier transform?

Comment: When I tried to calculate the FT from exp(-a|t|), I got a huge list with separate solutions divided in small parts instead the usual result formula.

Comment: @TheBlackCat: I get as a result: `Piecewise((1/(tau*(1 + 2*I*pi*w/tau)) + 1/(tau*(1 - 2*I*pi*w/tau)), And(Or(And(Abs(periodic_argument(exp_polar(-I*pi/2)*polar_lift(w), oo)) < pi/2, Abs(periodic_argument(tau, oo)) < pi/2), And(Abs(periodic_argument(exp_polar(-I*pi/2)*polar_lift(w), oo)) < pi/2, Abs(periodic_argument(tau, oo)) <= pi/2), And(Abs(periodic_argument(exp_polar(-I*pi/2)*polar_lift(w), oo)) <= pi/2, Abs(periodic_argument(tau, oo)) < pi/2)), Or(And(Abs(periodic_argument(exp_polar(I*pi/2)*polar_lift(w), oo)) < pi/2, Abs(periodic_argument(tau, oo)) < pi/2), ... )`

Comment: What is the equation you use?

Comment: `integrate(exp(-tau*abs(t))*exp(-I*2*pi*t*w), (t, -oo, oo))` @TheBlackCat

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `fourier_transform` function?

Comment: Because I did not know that such a function exists... Thanks!